# running kestrel webserver on .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, kestrel-http-server

how to host the kestrel web server in a application running under .net framework 4.5.x or 4.6.x. Currently I am getting an error saying that

"Unable to load DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Running kestrel on .net 4.xx has benefits of being an embedded web server that can be used to serve web pages from windows services etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same problem, it seems that the libuv library is not copied across to the bin directory during builds. If you look in your references you will see that libuv is not there even though it is a nuget package.

I can get the problem to go away by manually copying the library from the packages folder for my system to the bin\Debug or release folders.

Which does resolve the problem but is not a nice experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by setting your application run either in x86 or x64. Libuv will not work in conjunction with AnyCPU executables.